# Correspondance checking software

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, math-software

There's a Gamma distribution $P(A=z)≈\frac{2^{n/2}}{\sqrt{2z\pi}}\exp^{-\frac{z}{2^{1-n}}}$ for $z > 0$ and $0$ otherwise. This distribution has mean
$\mu(A) = 2^{-n}$ and standard deviation $\sigma(A)=\sqrt{2}\times2^{-n}$.
There're a random variable $v$ and its $K$ observations.
I'm looking for a software that will determine if this random variable $v$ matches given distribution by using $K$ observations.
First of all, I need the **software** itself and then mathematical explanation.

Comment: Can you program? Do you mind using R or Python?

Comment: I am not a regular here on math.se, but this seems inappropriate. I believe this  is a site for asking for guidance with a specific problem, not asking for free services.

Comment: @LarryB, yes, I can program. If you suggest a approriate libraries for this purpose, it would be great.

Comment: @erip, I looking for a software dealing with statictics (such as Mathematica, etc.). But I'm not an expert in this field, that is why I've asked

Comment: What leads you to think that the distribution you gave is a "Gamma" distribution? I tried the mean and standard deviation you gave, but they do not seem to match with the definition of Gamma distribution I've found.

Comment: @LarryB. oh, sure. I've made a typo. $\sigma = \sqrt(2)\times2^{-n}$. I've lost a sign before $n$.

Comment: When I use the parameters $k = 2^{-1}, \theta = 2^{1-n}$, I get the equation $\frac{2^{n/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}z^{-3/2}\exp \frac{-z}{2^{1-n}}$ for the probability density function

Comment: Gamma distribution is $f(z) = \frac{x^{k-1}}{\theta^k\Gamma(k)}\exp^{-x/\theta}$, if $k = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\theta = 2^{1-n}$ ($n$ is const), then we get $f(z)≈\frac{z^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{(2^{1-n})^\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}\exp^\frac{-z}{2^{1-n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}2^{\frac{n}{2}}\exp^\frac{-z}{2^{1-n}} = \frac{2^{n/2}}{\sqrt{2z\pi}}\exp^{-\frac{z}{2^{1-n}}}$.

I hope I've not made a mistake. I don't understand how you have derived $z^{-3/2}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the one-sample [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) to compare a sample with a reference distribution.

This is implemented in R as [ks.test](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dgof/versions/1.2/topics/ks.test).